# Using Firebase Firestore for tracking app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Quick question please. I am working on an on-demand app that uses live tracking which would require the constant update of people’s lat and lng, and I plan to you Firebase Firestore for it. Having read a few scary articles (lol scary in terms of costing) about how Cost shoot up overnight while using firestore. I’d like to know if it’s advisable to use firestore for this, as I think the entire BaaS it offers covers everything I need. If you can recommend the best approach possible to this, thanks

Comment: Flagging it because I am not sure if it is appropriate or not for stackoverflow.

The more appropriate question would be to implement something and ask for a better approach and alternative (1/2)

Comment: On the other hand, Since I am also building something like this, I am more concern with pricing of Maps than pricing of firestore. (2/2)

Comment: I think mapbox is cost efficient. I know how to implement i, but I don’t want to implement it and start building all over again if it turns out to be cost inefficient.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thank you .. noted

Comment: This seems to be opinion based questions, if it's expensive or not it would depend on who answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how large is your userbase and how frequently you want to update their current location.
Under the Flame Plan ($25/month) 100k document writes per day for firestore is supported. If you want more than that you'll need Blaze Plan (pay as you go).

See the pricing for details:
https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: Not voting but your answer seems to be in-appropriate to what OP asked. I am sure he would have checked the pricing online and is more interested in real-word experience than pricing. Also, If I were you, I would've added this as a comment.

Comment: @iRohitBhatia thanks for suggestion. Will follow it henceforth.